# Улучшить качество видео

Tags: python, алгоритм, opencv, машинное-обучение, поиск-программ

Есть видео низкого качества, плохо просматриваются объекты. Задача распознать объекты на видео. Кто сталкивался с улучшением видео?

Думаю это вполне реально с использованием нейросетей.

Comment: Нейросети будут просто додумывать объекты, базируясь на своём опыте

Comment: Да, я это понимаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Есть](https://tjournal.ru/36647-pochti-kak-v-serialah-razrabotchik-nauchil-neiroset-uluchshat-kachestvo-foto-nizkogo-razresheniya) наработки для фото, пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

причем при помощи всего лишь 340 строк кода

[Есть](https://vc.ru/n/google-image-zoom) наработки для более плохого качества, пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но имейте ввиду, что в любом случае, чем хуже качество исходного изображения тем неправдоподобнее восстановление.

Эти наработки можно и для видео переделать, но это уже зависит от ваших ресурсов.